# Promise each with return value

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a promise.each function which iterator the arr array and call the test function as follow :

```
var promise = require("bluebird");
var arr = [1,2,3];

function test(item) {
  return promise.resolve('change..');
}

return promise.each(arr, function(item) {
  return test(item);
})
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

The result will be [1,2,3]. Is there any way that I can change the result to [change.. , change.. , change..] ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why require **bluebird**? Node.js supports promises by default.

Comment: @EvanPlaice: For example because native promises don't have `each` or `map` methods :-)

Comment: @Bergi Really? http://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/14-map-in-parallel.html

Comment: @EvanPlaice: Yes, you can use `Promise.all`+`Array::map`, but that doesn't present the options and efficiency of Bluebird's `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`Promise.map`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html). Or if you want to ensure a sequential execution, [`Promise.mapSeries`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html) (since v3.0.1).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It really helps.